# How to make string interpreted as bytes?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x

Python 2 `str` compatable with `bytes`, but on Python 3 `str` is `unicode`.

I working on porting some project to Python3, but with support Python2.7.
This prodject has tests with many string constants. Also there is few `'...'.join(...)` and `'...'.format(...)`.

How to make Python3 to `b'123' == '123'` ?

Comment: You can't. Encode to bytes explicitly instead.

Comment: To gain compatibility from Py2.6 to 3.x, you might consider using `from __future__ import unicode_literals`

Comment: with `unicode_literals` i need to rewrite constants, but i dont know that compared with bytes, that with string returned from site lib.

Answer (score 3):

In Py3

```
>>> '123ü'.encode('utf-8')
b'123\xc3\xbc'
```

or

```
>>> bytes('123ü', 'utf-8')
b'123\xc3\xbc'
```

But you probably want to have it the other way around, and use UTF-8 in Py2 for easier transition. Using

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals`
```

to have all strings as `u''` in Py2.